# imported a movie now it has two audio tracks

Tags: audio, mp4, kdenlive

ok, so i ripped a dvd with handbrake, converted it to an mp4, i import the mp4 to kdenlive and kdenlive is doing this thing where it's giving me two audio tracks, so at first i thought it was a right ear audio track and a left ear audio track, and i was experimenting around and i deleted 1 audio track and it still sounds fine so it's weird it's not like there's a left ear and right ear track it's like they are both mono, now the issue is i just don't want there to be two tracks  because it just makes more work even if that work is only 1 step to delete the extra track, so i have no clue what's going on or how to merge the tracks, any ideas? how can i be able to import this video with only one audio track instead of two? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify if your videos only have a single audio stream as you believe them to have. It sounds like for whatever reason your videos have two streams that sound the same and so to you there should be no reason for them to show up twice.

Maybe something like either VLC or [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo)